# Seg fault in for loop?

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

So heres my for loops

```
string inputName;
int inputNumServices;
string inputServices[20];
do
{
  cin >> inputName;
  if(inputName != "$")
  {
    cin >> inputNumServices;
    for(int i = 0; i < inputNumServices; i++)
    {
      cin >> inputServices[i];
    }
    cout << "success";
  }
}
```

And it's giving me a seg fault after putting in all the inputs in the for loop. I know because it doesn't print out "success" before the seg fault

Comment: How do you declare `inputServices`?

Comment: just updated it sorry

Comment: Define "all inputs". What is the number you type when you run this program.

Comment: If you input more than 20 elements it will seg fault. I'd recommend using `std::vector` instead.

Comment: The code would definitely seg fault for values of inputNumServices > 20

Comment: and, for heaven's sake, *check your IO success/failure*

Comment: It still seg faults even when i reduce it to 5 values

Comment: The only way this code will seg fault if you enter fewer than 20 values would be if you failed to show a [mcve], and there's additional code that you failed to show, which triggers the bug.

Comment: What you've posted looks fine to me (if `inputNumServices <= 20`). My guess is that the segfault happens later, but you don't see the success output because you aren't flushing `cout`. You need to run your code through a debugger and post a [MCVE].

Comment: Where is the `while` of your `do`-loop?

Answer (score 0):

When I put this into `test.cc`

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
  string inputName;
  int inputNumServices;
  string inputServices[20];
  // I removed the "do" here, as commented by Nicky C
  {
    cin >> inputName;
    if(inputName != "$")
    {
      cin >> inputNumServices;

      for(int i = 0; i < inputNumServices; i++)
      {
        cin >> inputServices[i];
      }
      cout << "success";
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

and compile with `g++ test.cc -o test -Wall -Wextra` I can execute `test` without problems. (Other than I see the missing `endl` as pointed out by Kevin.)

With more than 20 inputs, it segfaults (as pointed out already, because the array only has 20 elements).